# thor incorrectly called exception

Tags: ruby, thor, invocation

```
class B12 < Thor
  desc "write", "write data into the index"
  method_option :methods, :desc => "The methods to call on each RawData", :type => :array
  def write(methods)
  end
end
```

When I call the file via

```
thor b12:write --methods=foo
```

I get

```
"write" was called incorrectly. Call as "thor b12:write".
```

Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple things going on here that'll cause issues.

First, you're using `methods`, which is a keyword in ruby.  That's going to cause all sorts of nonsense.  Use something else, like `my_methods`.

Second, you don't need to pass `my_methods` into write.  That creates a default option, not a named option.   So you'd call `thor b12:write foo` if you wanted access to `my_methods` in that context.

This works if you call it with: `thor b12:write --my_methods=foo`

```
class B12 < Thor
  desc "write", "write data into the index"
  method_option :my_methods, :type => :array, :desc => "The methods to call on each RawData"
  def write
    puts options.my_methods
  end
end
```